# UICollectionViewCell draw() method is not called after reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView in my project, but it does not draw the cells for the reused ones. Think that i have 20 cells when the app open, draw method is called 20 times. Then i change the number of cells to 30 and reload CollectionView, then draw method is called only 10 times. I want to call draw method 30 times, because i do some operations (adding images) in that method to cell.

**Note** :  I tested in iphone 5s (ios 10.3.3)

Below GameCollectionViewCell class is used as custom cell for CollectionView

```
extension GameCollectionViewCell {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

                var princess : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "CategoryImages/"+card!.contentImage)?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 )))

                var size : CGSize = CGSize(width: rect.size.width-1.8, height: rect.size.height-1.8)
                var origin : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x+0.9, y: rect.origin.y+0.9)
                var princessRect : CGRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

                princess.frame = princessRect
                princess.layer.masksToBounds =  true
                princess.layer.cornerRadius = 2;

                contentView.addSubview(princess)

            }
        }
```

Comment: please add any code you may have written... it is always best practice to share as much code as possible to make it easier for everyone

Comment: how many cells you have on the screen?

Comment: It changes. When i change  the number of  cells, i change also the number of rows and reload CollectionView

Comment: 1. Never attempt to override an existing method in an extension. Use a subclass. 2. It is a bad idea to override the `draw` method of `UICollectionViewCell`. Create a custom `UIView` class and put that view in the cell's `contentView`. 3. The code you have in your `draw` method does not belong in a `draw` method at all.

Comment: Try to look to last part of discussion in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw)

Comment: @RobertDresler Omg, thank you so much you saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much to @RobertDresler. He saved my day. After reloading CollectionView, if you call setNeedsDisplay() method then draw() method will be called.Please check below.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

        super.prepareForReuse()
        setNeedsDisplay()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you should not override a method in an extension, just like what you do in lifeCycle methods of your controllers (e.g. `viewDidLoad()`. Also note that you should, most of the times, call its `super.someFunc()`. Make a subclass instead.

When adding subviews in a subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`, put your codes inside the init method:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

If you are to change anything in your view's layer, you can override `layoutSubviews()`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue with my collection view, the best solution is to add functionality in your`GameCollectionViewCell` say `updateView()` and add the UI Elements to the subview

```
func updateView() {
    var princess : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "CategoryImages/"+card!.contentImage)?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 )))

            var size : CGSize = CGSize(width: rect.size.width-1.8, height: rect.size.height-1.8)
            var origin : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x+0.9, y: rect.origin.y+0.9)
            var princessRect : CGRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

            princess.frame = princessRect
            princess.layer.masksToBounds =  true
            princess.layer.cornerRadius = 2;

            addSubview(princess)
}
```

And inside the viewcontroller at while creating the cell for indexpath call the above method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! GameCollectionViewCell
    cell.updateView()       
    return cell
}
```